# Data not Appearing on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a header UIView which I am attempting to load JSON data on to, however no information displays at all, as shown: [image: pic 1]

Here is my method for loading my Header View:

```
- (ForeignInstagramViewHeader *)header {
    if (!_header) {
        _header = [[ForeignInstagramViewHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150) withUserData:self.instaUser];
        NSString *userID = self.instagramData[@"user"][@"id"];
        [self getInstaDataWithUserID:userID];
        _header.instaUser = self.instaUser;
    }
    return _header;
}
```

Here is my method for getting the Instagram Data:

```
- (void)getInstaDataWithUserID:(NSString *)user {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@", user];

     [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
         self.instaUser = [[InstagramUser alloc] init];
         [self.instaUser setBio:responseObject[@"data"][@"bio"]];
         self.instaUser.followed_by = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"followed_by"];
         self.instaUser.follows = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"follows"];
         self.instaUser.media = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"media"];
         self.instaUser.full_name = responseObject[@"data"][@"full_name"];
         self.instaUser.idvalue = responseObject[@"data"][@"id"];
         self.instaUser.profile_picture = responseObject[@"data"][@"profile_picture"];
         self.instaUser.username = responseObject[@"data"][@"username"];
         self.instaUser.website = responseObject[@"data"][@"website"];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

Here is my header View Class.h :

```
@interface ForeignInstagramViewHeader : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *profilePic;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * nameString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * postCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * postString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * followerCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * followerString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * followingCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * followingString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * bioString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * websiteString;

@property InstagramUser *instaUser;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withUserData:(InstagramUser *)instagram;
@end
```

Comment: You need to update data to header view after completion of `getPath:` for user data.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr how would I do that??

Answer (score 0):

In `ForeignInstagramViewHeader` class add a method to update UI with user details like,

```
- (void)updateWithUserDetails:(InstagramUser *)user {

    self.instaUser = user;
    // set values from user to lable's and other UI elements.
}
```

and header method will be

```
- (ForeignInstagramViewHeader *)header {
    if (!_header) {
        _header = [[ForeignInstagramViewHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150) withUserData:self.instaUser];
    }
    return _header;
}
```

and in `getInstaDataWithUserID:` method,

```
- (void)getInstaDataWithUserID:(NSString *)user {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@", user];

     [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
         self.instaUser = [[InstagramUser alloc] init];
         [self.instaUser setBio:responseObject[@"data"][@"bio"]];
         self.instaUser.followed_by = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"followed_by"];
         self.instaUser.follows = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"follows"];
         self.instaUser.media = responseObject[@"data"][@"counts"][@"media"];
         self.instaUser.full_name = responseObject[@"data"][@"full_name"];
         self.instaUser.idvalue = responseObject[@"data"][@"id"];
         self.instaUser.profile_picture = responseObject[@"data"][@"profile_picture"];
         self.instaUser.username = responseObject[@"data"][@"username"];
         self.instaUser.website = responseObject[@"data"][@"website"];

         //UPDATE
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [[self header] updateWithUserDetails:self.instaUser];
         });
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```